# Hide product options in email template for customer only not for admin

Tags: orders, customer, email, email-templates, custom-options

I want to customize email template for new order mail. I want to hide product options in mail for customers only, but want to show these product options in administrator mail. I am attaching a screen-shot for more clarification .

[image]

Please help me, how can I get done this task?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

I think both use the same email template and only sending it per BCC to the admin, so he knows what mails are sended.

You could hook via observer in an event after the checkout process gets completed and create an additional email with a separate template matching your needs.